# Admob banner not showing unless I put a breakpoint in the initState() function

Tags: flutter, admob

I tried following the AdMob tutorial

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-ads-in-flutter#6

but I can't seem to get the ad banner to work properly.

With the code the way it's currently set, the banner doesn't show up at all.
However, if I set a breakpoint at the line "_bannerAd.load();", the ad loads and the banner is displayed.

I can't figure out why, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'package:myapp/ad_helper_test.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'MyApp',
        theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const MyAppHomePage(title: 'MyApp'),
    );
  }
}

class MyAppHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyAppHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyAppHomePage> createState() => _MyAppHomePageState();
}

class _MyAppHomePageState extends State<MyAppHomePage> {
    late BannerAd _bannerAd;
    bool _isBannerAdReady = false;

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _bannerAd = BannerAd(
            adUnitId: AdHelper.bannerAdUnitId,
            request: const AdRequest(),
            size: AdSize.banner,
            listener: BannerAdListener(
                onAdLoaded: (_) {
                    setState(() {
                        _isBannerAdReady = true;
                    });
                },
                onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, err) {
                    print('Failed to load a banner ad: ${err.message}');
                    _isBannerAdReady = false;
                    ad.dispose();
                },
            ),
        );

        _bannerAd.load();
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
              buildAdWidget()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

    FutureBuilder<void> buildAdWidget() {
      return FutureBuilder<void>(
          future: _initGoogleMobileAds(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
              return Center(
                  child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                          if (_isBannerAdReady)
                              Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                                  child: SizedBox(
                                      width: _bannerAd.size.width.toDouble(),
                                      height: _bannerAd.size.height.toDouble(),
                                      child: AdWidget(ad: _bannerAd),
                                  ),
                              ),
                              
                          const Text("Here goes the rest of the app"),
                      ],
                  ),
              );
          },
      );
    }



    Future<InitializationStatus> _initGoogleMobileAds() {
        return MobileAds.instance.initialize();
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
      super.dispose();
      _bannerAd.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: In the tutorial `MobileAds.instance.initialize();` is initialized before a banner is attempted to be loaded... I can't help but think that this is your problem. You're initializing a banner before you're initializing the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation you need to initialize the framework `MobileAds.instance.initialize();` before loading a banner. You are doing the opposite. Consider wrapping your homepage with a `FutureBuilder` that initializes the framework and renders your homepage when it is initialized otherwise returns some loading page.

In the tutorial they're handling this with routes. Which is probably a fair way to go.

*edit*

This is not tested but it should look something like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'package:myapp/ad_helper_test.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const DependencyLoader(),
    );
  }
}

class DependencyLoader extends StatelessWidget {
  const DependencyLoader({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: MobileAds.instance.initialize(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          MyAppHomePage(
            title: 'MyApp',
          );
        } else {
          /// Create a loading page of some sort
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyAppHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyAppHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyAppHomePage> createState() => _MyAppHomePageState();
}

class _MyAppHomePageState extends State<MyAppHomePage> {
  late BannerAd _bannerAd;
  bool _isBannerAdReady = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _bannerAd = BannerAd(
      adUnitId: AdHelper.bannerAdUnitId,
      request: const AdRequest(),
      size: AdSize.banner,
      listener: BannerAdListener(
        onAdLoaded: (_) {
          setState(() {
            _isBannerAdReady = true;
          });
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, err) {
          print('Failed to load a banner ad: ${err.message}');
          _isBannerAdReady = false;
          ad.dispose();
        },
      ),
    );

    _bannerAd.load();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[buildAdWidget()],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildAdWidget() {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          if (_isBannerAdReady)
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: _bannerAd.size.width.toDouble(),
                height: _bannerAd.size.height.toDouble(),
                child: AdWidget(ad: _bannerAd),
              ),
            ),
          const Text("Here goes the rest of the app"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _bannerAd.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually saw the routes in their example, but have never used routes that way, just regular old push/pop. What would be the advantage of using routes the way they do ever just using a future builder ? Speaking of which, why not use a future builder that returns the MaterialApp directly instead of an extra class ?

Comment: Personally, I don't have a preference. Just depends on what your app needs. And as far as using a FutureBuilder that returns the material app that's all a fine way to go. At my company we have a `Dependencies` widget that does that work and setups up our Providers. The child of that `Dependencies` widget is the `MaterialApp`.  So a very valid route.

Comment: Thanks. I am only using Dart for my side projects, haven't used it professionally yet, in fact never wrote mobile apps for my job, so I always try to figure out what the best practices are.

Comment: Well let me clarify. Routes are great if you need to hop around your app. Pushing and popping to get from one section to another wouldn't be sustainable. So if you have an app with a lot of different deep nested stacks they become very valuable. If you have a simple app it might be overkill.

Comment: Thanks for all the explanation. I went for the future builder that returns the MaterialApp, and so far, so good.